# How to create a google doc for each row of a spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Yo!
This is my code that uses the last line of a spreadsheet to generate a google docs, in addition, it places a link to this document in the source spreadsheet. Is it possible to create code that does this for all rows in a worksheet? I'm having trouble using .range() to read the lines individually. The reason for this is simply to maintain and update generated versus updated data.

In advance, thank you!

```
var app=SpreadsheetApp.openById("Google ID");
var sheet=app.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1')


function autoFillLastRow() {

  var range=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var elem = range.pop();

  //e.values is an array of form values
  var timestamp = elem[0];

  //conversor de datas
  let data = new Date(timestamp);
  let dataFormatada = ((data.getDate() )) + "/" + ((data.getMonth() + 1)) + "/" +   data.getFullYear(); 

  var firstName = elem[1];
  var lastName = elem[2];
  var title = elem[3];
  
  //file is the template file, and you get it by ID
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('Google Drive ID'); 
  
  //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
  //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Google Drive ID')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(dataFormatada + ', ' + firstName, folder); 
  
  //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
  body.replaceText('{{Nome}}', firstName); 
  body.replaceText('{{Sobrenome}}', lastName);  
  body.replaceText('{{Título}}', title); 
  
  //Lastly we save and close the document to persist our changes
  doc.saveAndClose(); 

  //edit cell
  var coluna = 5;
  var linha = sheet.getLastRow();
  var docId = doc.getId();
  sheet.getRange(linha, coluna,1,1).setValue("https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + docId);


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Create document for every row of spreadsheet

```
   function createDocforEveryRowofSpreadsheet() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Google ID");
      var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1')
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('Google Drive ID');
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Google Drive ID')
      var [hA,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
      vs.forEach((r,i) =>  {
        var ts = r[0];
        let data = new Date(ts);
        let dataFormatada = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ts), Spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
        var firstName = r[1];
        var lastName = r[2];
        var title = r[3];
        var copy = file.makeCopy(dataFormatada + ', ' + firstName, folder);
        var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
        var body = doc.getBody();
        body.replaceText('{{Nome}}', firstName);
        body.replaceText('{{Sobrenome}}', lastName);
        body.replaceText('{{Título}}', title);
        doc.saveAndClose();
      })
    }
```

Comment: First, thank you very much, this way the code is infinitely cleaner! But my obstacle is seeing this variable correctly: 
var [hA,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
And unfortunately the code can't follow with this syntax:
vs.forEach((r,i) => ()) {
Could you help me? (I'm using google apps script for this)

Comment: The assumption for this function was that their was one header row which is placed into the hA and the rest of the data is placed in the two dimensional array vs so the code following that line is simply a forEach array method.